# When writing Web Api method in .Net is it necessary to have the method name prefix with HTTP code like GET, Post etc?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When writing Web Api method in .Net is it necessary to have the method name prefix with HTTP code like `GET`, `POST` etc?
Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts();
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id);
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(Product prod);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not necessary, but it's one of several conventions to map HTTP verbs to action methods. You could, for example, do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult AllProducts();
```

or this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts();
```

and they would both handle `GET` requests.

Comment: so it means every method should always has either attribute or Get word as prefix...correct ?

Comment: Yeah. There are more details in [the documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) (search for "http methods" on that page, the section wasn't link-able).

Answer (score 0):

If you utilise attribute routing you don't need to.

[Have a read of the docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes)

eg:

The following example maps the CreateBook method to HTTP POST requests.

```
[Route("api/books")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateBook(Book book) { ... }
```